# React-router-dom nesting doesn't work in children components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

For visualisation and clear picture, I will show the app's screen shot first.

[image]

I'm using github api to fetch Repos and Users. Simple. Now this how App.tsx looks;

```
// App.tsx
import React from "react";
import MainSearchPage from "./Components/MainSearchPage";
import Header from "./Components/Header";
import "./Sass/main.scss";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <MainSearchPage />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This is the MainSearchPage component;

```
// MainSearchPage.tsx
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { GithubContext } from "../Context/GithubContext";
import searchPc from "../Icons/search-pc.svg";
import SearchResults from "./SearchResults";

const MainSearchPage: React.FC = () => {
  const { isSearched } = useContext(GithubContext);
  return (
    <div>
      {isSearched ? (
        <SearchResults />
      ) : (
        <div className="blank-search-page">
          <div className="blank-search-page__items">
            <img src={searchPc} alt="search-pc" />
            <p>Search results will appear here</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MainSearchPage;
```

When input changes, isSearch becomes true and SearchResults is rendering. This is the SearchResults, where the problem begins.

```
//SearchResults.tsx
import React from "react";
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import MainSearchResults from "./MainSearchResults";
import SideBarSearchResults from "./SideBarSearchResults";
import UsersPage from "./UsersPage";

const SearchResults = () => {
  return (
    <div className="search-results">
      <Router>
        <SideBarSearchResults />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={MainSearchResults} />
          <Route path="/search-users" component={UsersPage} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchResults;
```

So MainSearchResults is basically repo results on the right. Sidebar is obvious I suppose. And UsersPage is the component that should be rendered when I click the Users on the left. But nothing happens when I click. Url changes and that's it. No errors in the console or anything. It was working before I put "isSearched" state. But I don't think it should matter.

SideBar component;

```
//SideBarSearchResults.tsx
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import repositoriesSVG from "../Icons/repositories.svg";
import usersSVG from "../Icons/users.svg";
import bookmarkblackSVG from "../Icons/bookmarkblack.svg";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { GithubContext } from "../Context/GithubContext";
const SideBarSearchResults: React.FC = () => {
  const { repoCount, userCount } = useContext(GithubContext);
  return (
    <div className="side-bar-search-results">
      <Link to="/">
        <div className="side-bar-search-results__repositories">
          <img src={repositoriesSVG} alt="repo" />
          <p className="result-title">Repositories</p>
          <p className="quantity">{repoCount ?? 0}</p>
        </div>
      </Link>
      <Link to="/search-users">
        <div className="side-bar-search-results__users">
          <img src={usersSVG} alt="users" />
          <p className="result-title">Users</p>
          <p className="quantity">{userCount ?? 0}</p>
        </div>
      </Link>
      <div className="side-bar-search-results__bookmarked ">
        <img src={bookmarkblackSVG} alt="bookmarked" />
        <Link to="/repo-details">
          <p className="result-title">Bookmarked</p>
        </Link>
        <p className="quantity">15</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SideBarSearchResults;
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: So what exactly is the issue? Where is the nesting? Or rather, what specific, if any, nesting are you referring to? I see 1 router, switch, and routes. Is the issue that Links in your `SideBarSearchResults` (?? just guessing) are not routing correctly to nested routes in `UsersPage`?

Comment: No errors in the console, nothing appearing. url changes and that's it. nothing else is happening. Sorry I should probably add this to question.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now, clicking "users" in the sidebar is supposed to route to `"/search-users"` path, but this isn't working? Can you include that sidebar component in your question?

Comment: @DrewReese I added, yes the url changes. But nothing else changes. Search results populate the userspage as you can see. But I can't reach it.

Comment: D'oh, issue was staring us in the face from the beginning. Classic react-router-dom rookie mistake with `Switch` and path matching order. Answered below. Sorry for asking for more context when it wasn't necessary, but I just wanted to rule out any additional `Router` components wrapping the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The `Switch` component matches and renders the ***first*** matched path, and "/" is a prefix for *every* path. In other words, it will always be the path matched and returned first.

## Solution

Reorder your `Route`s to specify the more specific paths first, and go in descending order of path specificity.

```
<Router>
  <SideBarSearchResults />
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/search-users" component={UsersPage} />
    <Route path="/" component={MainSearchResults} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: Jesus.. I'm just speechless. It actually took me 1 day to just switch the order... Thank you very much man

Comment: Instead of reordering it, making the `/` route exact solves the problem? like: <Route path="/" exact component={MainSearchResults} />

Comment: @Mateen Yes, that also would resolve this issue, but (IMO) adding the `exact` prop just to force a match is unnecessary since the `Switch` will only return a single match at most and by ordering routes correctly you can eliminate the need to add extra props.

Comment: You're right. But paying heed to orders is an overhead. Isn't it?

Comment: @Mateen Overhead, yes, I suppose there is some overhead involved. Searching the children routes for a matching path is an `O(n)` operation here, regardless of order, especially considering there is no set order other than how they are declared in JSX/DOM. It's all the same overhead.

Comment: @Drew Reese So reach router path ranking is a good thing to consider here. So, I wrote an answer as a complement to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to Drew Reese's anwer answer:

When you use any *route matching component* you need to know how it works so that you may go for another library.
In case `react-router` `<Router/>`, it doesn't render a component exclusively by default. Meaning, your application could possibly end up matching two paths for one route and renders the first one so **order does matter**.
For example, if you want to route `'/products'`, it matches both `/` and `/products`. **That was your case**. How to solve this:

- use `exact` or,
- reorder the *routes*, what **Drew Reese** just mentioned in his answer.

**Alternative:**

What if you don't like this path matching of `react-router?`
Here you have [Reach Router](https://reach.tech/router/ranking) whose path matching is a bit different. Reach Router *ranks* the paths and renders the one that makes the most sense. You can read about their [path ranking](https://reach.tech/router/ranking). So, you don't need to think about the orders or using an extra keyword `exact` because *reach router* itself prioritizes the router using the *path ranking**system*.

Comment: FYI, the `Router` components render routes inclusively (all matching routes/redirect/component), the `Switch` changes this behavior and renders routes exclusively (first matching route/redirect). The behavior you describe is included in `react-router-dom v6` where essentially Reach Router and React Router are merging. In react-router-dom v6 the `Switch` component is replaced by a `Routes` component and uses a path ranking system. https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/#introducing-routes